# Valid value for the "name" attribute in HTML

Tags: html

I use PHP to get radio button values from an HTML page. My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="1.1" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="1.1" value="no">

<input type="radio" name="1" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="1" value="no">
```

The result is that $_POST['1'] returns a value, but $_POST['1.1'] returns nothing. I checked the HTML 4 specifications, say value for the *name* attribute only starts with a letter, but 1 is not a letter. How come it gets returned while 1.1 does not? Or is there some other magic happening here? I use the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By HTML rules, the `name` attribute may have any value: it is declared with CDATA type. Do not confuse this attribute with the references to attributes declared as having NAME type. See *[17.4 The INPUT element, name = cdata [CI]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT)*.

In the use of `$POST[...]` in PHP, you need to note this PHP rule: “Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.” See *[Variables From External Sources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)*.

So `$_POST['1']` should work as is and does work, but instead of `$_POST['1.1']` you need to write `$_POST['1_1']`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the second link!

Comment: Here is the corresponding HTML5 doc of the name attribute: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela:  What does it mean, if you write `Do not confuse the with the references to attributes declared as having NAME type.`? Where or what is the difference?

Comment: Attributes declared as having `NAME` type were an HTML 4 concept based on its being formally an SGML application. The `NAME` keyword in the formal definition of an attribute indicated that that the attribute value must start with a letter and may contain only letters, digits, and underscores. Attributes declared so have “NAME” in the “Type” column in the [Index of Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) (in the HTML 4 spec). This concept is not used any more since HTML5, which does not use SGML formalisms.

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"...confuse the with the references"*.

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting the period for something else like a hyphen. In both the form and the PHP code. Periods are generally used for a `.` in the extension name.

When it comes to key names for parameters in either [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) or [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) headers, you want to only use alphanumeric characters, with some special characters generally. Such as hyphens, underscores, etc. You can always do a URL encode if you need to as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your input items with text, not numbers.  They should not contain any characters such as `.`, `,`, `!`, and `?`. This can cause problems.  For more information submitting the data, go to *[PHP and HTML Radio Buttons](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html)*