# PHP curl file upload :: weird curl behaviour when form name is an integer

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I have problem with curl file upload using PHP when form name of input file is an integer: `<input type="file" name="1">`

I have following array that I put in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to get multipart/form-data:

```
$array = array(
    "MAX_FILE_SIZE" => 80000,
    "1" => '@'.$cfg['lpath'].'logos/'.domain($projekt['adres']).'.jpg;type=image/jpeg',
    "2" => '@'.($cfg['lpath']==''?'/dev/null':'NUL:').';filename=',
    "3" => '@'.($cfg['lpath']==''?'/dev/null':'NUL:').';filename=',
    "send" => 'send it'
);
```

I send it to server and var_dump($_POST, $_FILES) is as follow:

$_POST:

```
array(2) {
  ["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]=>
  string(5) "80000"
  ["send"]=>
  string(7) "send it"
}
```

$_FILES:

```
array(1) {
  ["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
   ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

When I change array keys to letters it works as expected:

$_FILES:

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "filename.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpRZMiRA"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(6567)
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["c"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Is it a bug? Is it possible to send such an array using curl?

My PHP Version is 5.3.25
Curl version 7.30.0

Answer (score 0):

Name tokens in HTML have to follow a certain restriction.

```
6.2 SGML basic types

...

    ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata

One solution could be to prefix your inputs with say "data-"`<number>` and your post would work as expected.

There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow that address this issue. Here is one: [valid value for name attribute in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369295/valid-value-for-name-attribute-in-html)

Comment: I don't have access to this HTML form and I need to send data via curl. Maybe using php cocket would do the trick.

Comment: Would it be possible to try and contact the author/responsible and ask for a rather simple change? Working off plain wrong convention is a hack at best.