# document.querySelector for name as css selector?

Tags: jquery, html

I know document.querySelector('..') takes css selector as arguments like

> a.className, #idName, etc....

But I am not sure how to use name.
I saw an example but couldnt understand it .

```
document.querySelector('[name="billContact.email"]')
```

Comment: Attribute value selector see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: what is billContact and what is email. Is email a class and billContact a name attribute ?

Comment: `"billContact.email"` is the value of attribute `name`

Comment: what may be the possible div syntax for this ?

Comment: When you post a question please make sure you post all your clarifications in the description instead of asking in comments. And post what code or example you are stuck with. A single line doubt without the relevant code is not the way to ask questions. Please be clear.

Comment: I have already got my answer within 2-3 comments just asking example so that i can be sure, don't comment unnecessarily on every post you think u can.  I am not writing a piece of code , just querying about a single topic for `document.querySelector`. I read all about this however was unable to understand how one thing works so asked that particular piece of code clearly. There was no point of explaining what i am doing and what i want to do, I asked specificly what line i was not clear about and THANKS to **SATPAL** . He made it clear

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

`[`*HTML-Node-Attribute*`="`*Value*`"]`

---

### Attribute selectors

The HTML-Element-Attributes `id` and `class` does have there own css-selecoring:

- `#id`
- `.class`

The others attributes do need something else. Like "Attribute selectors".

So for example you have the following like of HTML Code:

```
<a href="#top">Go to top!</a>
```

With Attribut selectors you can *get* this element with all the following posibilities:

```
[href] /*looking only for the attribut. No matter what value is inside*/
[href="#top"] /*the attributes value must be "#top"*/
a[href="#top"] /*the same as the example above but in this case href needs to be a attribute of "a"-tag*/
```

There are some more very cool posibilities to address an element. For more infos see [MDN Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

### `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`

> `querySelector` gives you the first element which equals the passed
>   css-selector.

Okay, I guess this may be much easier to understand with examples instead of a wall of text. So let's start:

For this example I'm gonna use this HTML-snipped:

```
<div class="container">
    <div data-id='cat'>
        <button name='cat' value='miau'>Cat</button>
    </div>
    <div data-id='dog'>
        <button name='dog' value='not miau'>Dog</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you aksed about how to find a element by it's name with `querySelector`, I'll start with that:

There are two elements with a name attribut. Both are buttons but have different names.

To get the first element with a name attribute use:

```
document.querySelector('[name]') //get button cat because it's the first one in the dom (in that example)
```

To get them all try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name]') //get both buttons (cat, dog)
```

When you know the name what you're looking for use

```
document.querySelector('[name="cat"]') //get the first element where name equals 'cat'
```

Same with other attributes like data, class or id

```
document.querySelector('[data-id="cat"]') //get div
```

You can also do more dom steps at once:

```
document.querySelector('[data-id="cat"] button') //gets the first button inside "cat-div"
```

### Docs

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869405(v=vs.85).aspx) for more informations.
You may also be interested in [CSS-Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) as well.

Comment: Long answer, explaining how the `querySelector` works, but not to the actual question. OP states he knows how querySelector works :)

Comment: @Martijn Oops, you are right. I'll edit my answer in a few mins.

Answer (score 2):

It means "everything with `name='billContact.email'`"

P.S Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370025/5165019) for more info

Answer (score 2):

You can use **document.querySelectorAll** to find the element using attribute.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name="test"]');
```

Comment: can u tell a div syntax where 
`document.querySelector('[name="billContact.email"]')`
will acess the billContact.email selector.

Answer (score -1):

For document.querySelector('[name="billContact.email"]')
your input tag is needed has below;

You can try ('input[name="billContact.email"]'):

```
function checkForm(){
 var form = document.forms[0];
 var selectElement = form.querySelector('input[name="billContact.email"]');
 var selectedValue = selectElement.value;
```

}

Next time consult https://developer.mozilla.org 
 and this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2ZL4G/167/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants to understand the why, this is just an example of showing how to which OP was curious about in the first place.